# Possible Ways to use Func T, bool while using a LINQ Repository

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql, repository-pattern

I found many examples of generic repository using LINQ to SQL. However there is not enough examples about how to call these functions. Can you please provide an example about how to use the following functions by a client?

Note: My question is about the use of **Func T,bool**. What are the **possible ways** to use it?

Note: BankAccount is an entity.

```
class MyRepository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
{
    ..........

    public IEnumerable<T> FindAll(Func<T,bool> predicate)
    {
        return Context.GetTable<T>().Where(predicate);
    }

    public T FindByID(Func<T,bool> predicate)
    {
        return Context.GetTable<T>().SingleOrDefault(predicate);
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

Based on response, I used it as follows;

```
 public RepositoryLayer.Account FindFirstAccount()
    {
        Func<RepositoryLayer.Account, bool> predicate = (p => p.AccountNumber == 1);
        List<RepositoryLayer.Account> accList =  (accountRepository.FindAll(predicate)).ToList();
        return accList[0];
    }
```

Note: List RepositoryLayer.Account accList = (List RepositoryLayer.Account) accountRepository.FindAll(predicate); will not work

Comment: just one detail : if `Context.GetTable<T>` returns an `IQueryable<T>`, the parameter of FindAll should be an `Expresson<Func<T, bool>>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways to specify Func, which is in essence a `delegate` which takes one parameter and returns a bool.

The most convenient way in most situations is to specify it as a Lambda expression, such as:

```
var repo = new Repository<BankAccount>();
repo.FindById(account=>account.Id == 15);
```

The other ways of specifying Func are best described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151.aspx).

EDIT:
To fix your latest error, you need the results as List. Remove your explicit cast and try:

```
accountRepository.FindAll(predicate).ToList();
```

Comment: Well, what's the problem? If you're going to downvote at least say why it's wrong.

Answer (score 3):

For instance:

```
var repository = new MyRepository<Person>();
var personsOlderThan50 = repository.FindAll(p=>p.Age > 50);
```

Comment: Thanks. I am getting an exception. Updated the question. Can you please answer?

Answer (score 2):

A Func T, bool is a delegate that accepts a generic parameter T and returns a bool.  In your case you would use the repository like

```
var repository = new MyRepository<BankAccount>;
var account = repository.FindByID(a=>a.AccountId == 10);
```